# Path to folder outside of folder and inside the folder

Tags: html, css

I stored my index.css in my css folder but the pictures i put here is outside the css folder and is inside the pics folder. I tried ../pics/walp.png but it's not working.

Comment: try adding one more `../` to `../pics/walp.png`

Comment: it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you compare the complete directory trees of both the .CSS and .PNG files and also make sure you have the exact path of .PNG file mentioned in the .CSS.

You may have to check it from the command line (in terminal), to get the complete folder paths.

Answer (score 0):

- For each time you go back a folder you have to make sure you include
  a ../ to represent going back a folder.
- Make sure spelling and capitalization are also in check.
- One other option is to see if you can use `/pics/walp.png`  -
  sometimes this works based on file structure and operating system (however, relative paths are always recommended if you can get it to work)
- Also, it would help to see the code you are using to make sure its
  not the code causing the problems instead of file paths.